# Magento 2.4 Get tracking Information from order/shipment

Tags: magento2, module, orders, customer, sales-order

[image]Track My Orders Using Order Status in Magento 2

- Pending as Ordered
- Processing as Accepted
- Shipping as On It's Way
- Completed as Delivered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example\Track\Controller\Order\Index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © magento2.
 */
namespace Example\Track\Controller\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Controller\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements OrderInterface, HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @var PageFactory
     *
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     *
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Customer order history
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Track My Order'));
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer.account.link.back');
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Example\Track\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © magento2.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Example_Track"></module>
</config>
```

**Example\Track\etc\frontend\routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="track" id="track">
            <module name="Example_Track"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Example\Track\view\frontend\layout\track_order_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © magento2.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History" name="track_order_index" template="Example_Track::order/index.phtml" cacheable="false" />
        </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

**Example\Track\view\frontend\templates\index.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento2.
 */
/** @var \Example\Track\Block\Order\Index $block */
?>
<?php
$_orders = $block->getOrders();
?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('info') ?>
<?php if ($_orders && count($_orders)): ?>
    <div class="table-wrapper orders-history">
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= /* @noEscape */ date("l jS  F Y", strtotime($_order->getCreatedAt())) ?></td>
                    <td><b><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('#ID ')) ?>
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_order->getRealOrderId()) ?></b></td>
                    <td><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('TOTAL PAID')) ?></td>
                    <td><b><?= /* @noEscape */ $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><svg class="tracking-icons " width="72.75" height="72.75" viewBox="0 0 72.75 72.75">
                            <g transform="translate(-1381.85 -621)">
                                <g class="circle" transform="translate(1381.85 621)"
                                   fill="none" stroke="#04823b" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4">
                                    <circle cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="36.375" stroke="none"></circle>
                                    <circle class="border" cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="34.375" fill="none"></circle>
                                </g>
                                <path class="tick" d="M3476.24,9228.867l-9.674-9.673,3.225-3.224,6.449,6.448,
                                    14.51-14.51,3.224,3.224Z" transform="translate(-2062.045 -8561.666)" fill="#04823b">
                                </path>
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                    </td>
                    <td><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Ordered')) ?></td>
                    <?php if ($_order->hasShipments() || $_order->getStatus() == 'processing'
                        || $_order->getStatus() == 'complete'): ?>
                        <td><svg class="tracking-icons " width="72.75" height="72.75" viewBox="0 0 72.75 72.75">
                                <g transform="translate(-1381.85 -621)">
                                    <g class="circle" transform="translate(1381.85 621)"
                                       fill="none" stroke="#04823b" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4">
                                        <circle cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="36.375" stroke="none"></circle>
                                        <circle class="border" cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="34.375" fill="none"></circle>
                                    </g>
                                    <path class="tick" d="M3476.24,9228.867l-9.674-9.673,3.225-3.224,6.449,6.448,
                                    14.51-14.51,3.224,3.224Z" transform="translate(-2062.045 -8561.666)" fill="#04823b">
                                    </path>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
                        </td>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <td><svg class="tracking-icons " width="72.75" height="72.75" viewBox="0 0 72.75 72.75">
                                <g transform="translate(-1381.85 -621)">
                                    <g class="circle" transform="translate(1381.85 621)"
                                       fill="none" stroke="#e5e5e4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4">
                                        <circle cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="36.375" stroke="none"></circle>
                                        <circle class="border" cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="34.375" fill="none"></circle>
                                    </g>
                                    <path class="tick" d="M3476.24,9228.867l-9.674-9.673,3.225-3.224,6.449,6.448,
                                    14.51-14.51,3.224,3.224Z" transform="translate(-2062.045 -8561.666)" fill="#cbcaca">
                                    </path>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
                        </td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <td><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("Accepted")) ?></td>
                    <?php if ($_order->hasShipments()): ?>
                        <td><svg class="tracking-icons " width="72.75" height="72.75" viewBox="0 0 72.75 72.75">
                                <g transform="translate(-1381.85 -621)">
                                    <g class="circle" transform="translate(1381.85 621)"
                                       fill="none" stroke="#04823b" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4">
                                        <circle cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="36.375" stroke="none"></circle>
                                        <circle class="border" cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="34.375" fill="none"></circle>
                                    </g>
                                    <path class="tick" d="M3476.24,9228.867l-9.674-9.673,3.225-3.224,6.449,6.448,
                                    14.51-14.51,3.224,3.224Z" transform="translate(-2062.045 -8561.666)" fill="#04823b">
                                    </path>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
                        </td>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <td><svg class="tracking-icons " width="72.75" height="72.75" viewBox="0 0 72.75 72.75">
                                <g transform="translate(-1381.85 -621)">
                                    <g class="circle" transform="translate(1381.85 621)"
                                       fill="none" stroke="#e5e5e4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4">
                                        <circle cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="36.375" stroke="none"></circle>
                                        <circle class="border" cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="34.375" fill="none"></circle>
                                    </g>
                                    <path class="tick" d="M3476.24,9228.867l-9.674-9.673,3.225-3.224,6.449,6.448,
                                    14.51-14.51,3.224,3.224Z" transform="translate(-2062.045 -8561.666)" fill="#e5e5e4">
                                    </path>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
                        </td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <td><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("On it's Way")) ?></td>
                    <?php if ($_order->hasShipments() && $_order->getStatus() == 'complete'): ?>
                        <td><svg class="tracking-icons " width="72.75" height="72.75" viewBox="0 0 72.75 72.75">
                                <g transform="translate(-1381.85 -621)">
                                    <g class="circle" transform="translate(1381.85 621)"
                                       fill="none" stroke="#04823b" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4">
                                        <circle cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="36.375" stroke="none"></circle>
                                        <circle class="border" cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="34.375" fill="none"></circle>
                                    </g>
                                    <path class="tick" d="M3476.24,9228.867l-9.674-9.673,3.225-3.224,6.449,6.448,
                                    14.51-14.51,3.224,3.224Z" transform="translate(-2062.045 -8561.666)" fill="#04823b">
                                    </path>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
                        </td>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <td><svg class="tracking-icons " width="72.75" height="72.75" viewBox="0 0 72.75 72.75">
                                <g transform="translate(-1381.85 -621)">
                                    <g class="circle" transform="translate(1381.85 621)"
                                       fill="none" stroke="#e5e5e4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4">
                                        <circle cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="36.375" stroke="none"></circle>
                                        <circle class="border" cx="36.375" cy="36.375" r="34.375" fill="none"></circle>
                                    </g>
                                    <path class="tick" d="M3476.24,9228.867l-9.674-9.673,3.225-3.224,6.449,6.448,
                                    14.51-14.51,3.224,3.224Z" transform="translate(-2062.045 -8561.666)" fill="#e5e5e4">
                                    </path>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
                        </td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <td><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("Delivered")) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("You don't have any orders yet!")) ?></div>
<?php endif ?>
<?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
    <div class="orders-pagination"><?= $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

**Example\Track\registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright   © Magento2.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Example_Track',
    __DIR__
);
```